# Вопрос о валидации полей

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, валидация

Здравствуйте.
А каковы требования к таким полям как логин, e-mail и т.д.
какие у них максимальные значения или минимальные, требования к содержимому?

Comment: Какие установишь, такие и будут. Плюс контроль валидности для атрибутов, для которых он имеет смысл (например, e-mail).

Comment: @Akina, тое стандартов в этом вопросе нету?)

Comment: Есть стандарты на *некоторые* типы атрибутов. На то же мыло, к примеру - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322, или там на URL фотографии. Есть требования, налагаемые системой (скажем, только А-набор для логина) или иными обстоятельствами. Но на многое никаких устоявшихся требований нет.